# directory traverse c

Tags: c, unix, directory-traversal

I'm trying to traverse a directory and check for duplicate files.

```
void findDuplicates(){
    char *dot[] = {".", 0};
    FTS *ftsp, *temp_ftsp;
    FTSENT *entry, *temp_entry;
    int fts_options = FTS_LOGICAL;
    ftsp = fts_open(dot, fts_options, NULL);
    while((entry = fts_read(ftsp)) != NULL){
        temp_ftsp = ftsp;
        while((temp_entry = fts_read(temp_ftsp)) != NULL){
            compareEntries(temp_ftsp, ftsp);
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't traverse the directory the way I wanted to. After the 2nd while loop, the

```
entry = fts_read(ftsp)
```

returns NULL. Is there an easy fix for this or I should use something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-structure your approach. The inner `while` is exhausting the list of files, so of course the outer will fail after succeeding, once.

A better approach is probably to store the files so you can just compare each new incoming file against the stored ones, or use a recursive approach. Both will require memory.

Comment: Good point, I guess I'll have to do that. Storing all files in a structure sounds the easiest approach. Thanks.

Comment: @KlāvsTaube Feel free to upvote and/or accept, if you felt this helped. :)